# Can anyone know how to add tab at terminal start just like photo link? thanks a lot

Tags: mac, terminal

Just like subject, I miss my configuration with Terminal setting? anyone can help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the key sequence

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-T

This will show the Tab Panel

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new tab in the current window is accomplished with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> will add a new terminal tab.

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I want start Terminal with "+" at the staring.